# NetBeans Find Replace RegEx

Tags: regex, netbeans

I Want To Find Replace In My Project:

From:

```
SessionData::model()->get_session_data(SessionData::model()->get_profile_data(),'module')
```

To:

```
$this->user_token->module
```

Using Find Replace... How Can I Do That?

The "module" text can be anything I want to put that after user_token->%theanything%

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just click on „Edit“ -> „Replace in Projects…“ in the MenuBar and copy your „From“ text into „Containing Text“ and your „To“ text into „Replace With“, choose the right scope where to search and click continue. Maybe you want to set the "File Name Pattern" to *.php (or whatever extension your files code have) before clicking „Continue“. That should be it.

EDIT:

Match: `Regular Expression`

Containing Text:
`SessionData::model\(\)->get_session_data\(SessionData::model\(\)->get_profile_data\(\),'(.*)'\)`

Replace With: `\$this->user_token->$1`

Comment: The "module" text can be anything I want to put that after user_token->%theanything%

Comment: You should have mentioned that in the first place ;)
See the updates in my answer.

Comment: Thanks it is working but not deleting ') after the session name... For an example it is replacing like: $this->user_token->module')

Comment: I tried the line was:

url: '<?php echo Yii::app()->createAbsoluteUrl($this->route,array('sub_menu' => SessionData::model()->get_session_data(SessionData::model()->get_profile_data(),'child_menu'), 'form_submit' => 1,'render'=>'renderPartial')); ?>',

but it's not removed the first bracket rather removed last first bracket....

Thank you....

Comment: It seems there are some special characters in your code around get_profile_data, try this:
`SessionData::model\(\)->get_session_data\(SessionData::model\(\)-.*>get_profile_data\(\)\,.*'(.*)'\)`